# Appium - Disable bug report generation on Android

Tags: android, mobile, adb, appium, bug-reporting

I'm wondering if there's a way to disable the bug report function that appium does everytime a test fails, as this can be very time-consuming and I find myself just waiting for the report to generate when I don't even need it

sample from appium logs:

```
2018-07-20 15:29:31:770 - [HTTP] 

{"type":"bugreport","sessionId":"337b3e20-17d1-4b9d-a564-4107fbd6cd52"}
2018-07-20 15:29:31:770 - [debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.getLog() with args: ["bugreport","337b3e20-17d1-4b9d-a564-4107fbd6cd52"]
2018-07-20 15:29:31:771 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Retrieving 'bugreport' logs
2018-07-20 15:29:31:771 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Retrieving supported log types
2018-07-20 15:29:31:771 - [debug] [ADB] Running '/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 04db2741df5621fc bugreport'
```

Checking in Android Developer tools on multiple device versions I've found no option to turn this feature off, there is a 'Take bug report' option which does not seem to be what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in the same issue as you and worked it around by wrapping my adb into a proxy script that drops any bug report request. It's not the definitive solution, but it works and saves a large amount of time.

Just go to your Android SDK, rename adb to adb-real, then create a script named adb and make sure to set execution permissions. Here's the Bash script, if you happen to be using Windows you might want to create some other kind of script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$*" =~ .*bugreport.* ]]
then
    echo "Ignoring bugreport"
else
    adb-real $*
fi
```